# How to customize magento onepage checkout form

Tags: magento, checkout

i am using Magento 1.5.1.0 and i want to customize the address block in the onepage checkout form. I want to remove the "fax" input field and put the "region" dropdown below the country "dropdown". Where is this form defined?

Kind Regards,
Bertie

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Navigate to your theme folder.
The default file is at location:

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml
```

Comment: The same what i did in shipping.phtml i need to do in Billing.phtml right?

Answer (score 11):

You might need to change multiple files:

As above:

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml
```

but also...

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
```

and also...

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
```

Tada!

Answer (score 1):

Oh and don't forget `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\customer\address\edit.phtml`