# Change design checkout magento

Tags: css, magento

I have changed the design of all the normal pages like: **About Us**, **Home** and **Contact** with my own stylesheet by going to CMS -> Pages in the backend, but the checkout pages aren't there. Now whenever I want to checkout I go to the standard checkout page with a standard magento style(URL: `http://127.0.0.1/html/magento/index.php/checkout/cart/`). I want to get the same design of the other pages on my checkout pages. I've read this question: [How to customize magento onepage checkout form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194341/how-to-customize-magento-onepage-checkout-form) but that doesn't explain much how to get your own standard style in it + I was wondering if there isn't an easier way to do this. What is the easiest way to get my own design in the checkout pages? It was easy to get my own style in the other pages.

Comment: Do you have a new theme created with your CSS styles? Or are you doing this inline on the CMS page itself?

Comment: @FranklinPStrube I have a new theme created with my css styles.

Comment: Add/Remove your custom.css using xml only for cms pages or checkout. where u want. see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11860/adding-css-and-js-to-head-using-a-module-layout-xml-for-block

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change the design in the System Configuration. Go to Admin > System > Configuration then click on the General > Design tab. This is where you change the theme in use to whatever theme houses your CSS skin.

[image: Magento System Configuration Screenshot]